# Use of "salesy" secondary titles on Amazon

Tags: titles, sales

I was looking at the sales rankings on Amazon today with my publisher and he pointed out that all of the self-published best sellers have a short title then a semi-colon followed by a pitch line (see pic attached). I'm certainly not a fan, but the proof is evident that it gets visibility.

Does anyone have data-driven proof that this increases sales?[image: screenshot of Kindle top results for"thriller books"]

Comment: Speaking only as a reader: It's fine for non-fiction, *very* annoying for novels. Name the thing properly; you shouldn't have to explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data you are seeking is tightly held. Publishers and sellers don't really want you to know this.  They even hide a lot of stats about sales figures on books.

**Some Helpful Info**

However, I recently read the following book by an indie publisher which explains exactly what you're talking about: [Six Figure Author : Using Data To Sell Books (Chris Fox)](http://amzn.to/2oBpUzb)

**My Experience**

I had recently published a book which I titled : [Launch Your Android App](http://amzn.to/2qkdTKS)

The interesting thing is that the author of that hyperbolically named, aforementioned title explains that Amazon's search engine is completely based on titles.

**I Tested the Theory**

After 2 months or so of Launch Your Android App being for sale I had only sold 2 or 3 copies.  I decided to change the title and re-publish the book so that it was named similarly to other books in the category.
You can see the book with teh new title at: [Beginning Android Programming With Android Studio](http://amzn.to/2qbOlAs)

**Title Change Instantly Changed Sales**

This was amazing to me, because the next day after I changed the title, the book sold 3 or 4 copies.  After that, it sold a copy or two every day.  It's quite interesting and I believe the information you have is correct about how titles are used on Amazon.